# I am creating a reactive Grocery list using javascript and I want to change the color of list item when i click on it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the colour to red when I click on the list item and change it to black when I again click on it. This is the way I am trying to do...

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("list").style.background = "red";
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="mb-3" style="color: white; text-align: center;">GROCERY LIST</h1>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <input id="item" type="text" placeholder="New item..." maxlength="27">


      <div class=" row">
        <ul id="list" class="col-12">
        </ul>
```

this is the function to create list items.

```
 function Additem(){
        var a= document.getElementById("list");
        var b= document.getElementById("item");
        var li = document.createElement("li");
li.setAttribute('id',b.value);
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(b.value));
a.appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: But where is the list item?

Comment: This is what is looks like right now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRavV.png

Comment: Plz share the complete code...

Answer (score -1):

If you use jQuery you can use [.toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

**jQuery**

```
$('ul li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

**CSS**

```
ul li {
  background: black;
}

ul li.active {
  background: red;
}
```

If you want plain JavaScript you simple need and if else statement:

Here is a JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/prqmgf8L/